# Could not find method kapt() for Glide

Tags: android, gradle, android-glide, kapt

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.61"
```

I have the above gradle configuration, and still I am getting

```
Could not find method kapt() for arguments [com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.3.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Can someone tell me where am I going wrong? Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The project-level `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2"
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.70"
    }
}
```

The module-level `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: "kotlin-android"
apply plugin: "kotlin-android-extensions"
apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"
...
android {

} 
dependencies {
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0"
    // annotationProcessor "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0"
    kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0"
}
...
apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
```

Answer (score 10):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'kotlin-kapt' // add this line in file build.gradle (Module : YourAppName)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply must be under plugins this worked for me

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}
apply plugin: "kotlin-android-extensions"
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

And in the other build.grandle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version="1.4.0"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I think `kapt` is available with the new versions of [Glide](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/) so, try adding:

```
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
```

In your `Build.gradle` dependencies [when using Kotlin](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/download-setup.html#kotlin).

<sub>Note that the Glide dependency should have the same version as the compiler :</sub>

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
}
```

Or, try updating your Kotlin to v`1.2.71`:

```
buildscript {

    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
}


 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

**In the root** `Build.gradle`. This should work.

Comment: tried with Glide 4.8.0 as well getting the same error.

Comment: Try updating your kotlin to v1.2.71 and then see what happens? Check my updated answer.